# Pull a json var from an html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How can I extract the values of those variables and store them into a javascript var using jquery? This tag is stored in the header of an html document

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            var vip_ship_info = {
                "ship_address1":    "x",
                "ship_address2":    "x",
                "ship_country":     "x",
                "ship_postal":      "x",
                "office_title":     "x"
            };
    </script>
```

Comment: They are already stored in a javascript var. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: I was injecting javascript into a website to pull values and show them into an ios app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either `vip_ship_info.ship_address1` or `vip_ship_info["ship_address1"]`

Answer (score 1):

Your variable has already been declared, and so long as any referencing code is placed beneath this script block, you can access the inner variables as such:

```
var ship_address1 = vip_ship_info.ship_address1
```

Use dot notation to access values within objects. No jQuery needed.